# Which is the bigger population using t.test in R? How to tell to the function?

Tags: r, mean, population

I have a question about using t.test to check if the population mean is bigger than another.

Imagine I have 2 variables in a dataframe d:

```
Weight: Numerical variable (weight of people).
Anykids: Categorical variable that can be yes or no.
```

The dataframe would be like:

```
Anykids Weight
yes     70
yes     84
no      66
...     ..
```

I want to check if the mean of weight of people with anykids = yes is bigger than the one's with anykids = no. So I wold have:

```
H0: m(weight_yes) = m(weight_no)
H1: m(weight_yes) > m(weight_no)
```

The function would be:

```
t.test(weight~anykids, data = d, alternative = 'greater')
```

How the function knows that the parameter greater means the group with anykids = yes and not the group with anykids = no?

If I wanted to check the hypothesis:

```
H0: m(weight_no) = m(weight_yes)
H1: m(weight_no) > m(weight_yes)
```

The function would had the same parameters. How I know that greater means anykids = yes o anykids = no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like many things with factors, R chooses based on the order of the levels of the factor. In your case, you could check using `levels(Anykids)` to discover in advance which one will be used as *x* vs. *y* in the `t.test()` function, or potentially change the order with `relevel()`.

But the `t-test()` results will also just show you which one was considered. Here, in the iris dataset, the versicolor level comes first, and will be considered whether versicolor has a greater mean Sepal.Width than virginica.

```r
levels(iris$Species)
#> [1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"
test_data <- iris[iris$Species != 'setosa', ]
t.test(data = test_data, Sepal.Width ~ Species, alternative = "greater")
#> 
#>  Welch Two Sample t-test
#> 
#> data:  Sepal.Width by Species
#> t = -3.2058, df = 97.927, p-value = 0.9991
#> alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is greater than 0
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  -0.3096707        Inf
#> sample estimates:
#> mean in group versicolor  mean in group virginica 
#>                    2.770                    2.974
```